# Subsequent Variable Declarations must have the same type - Where do I find the original declaration

Tags: typescript

I declared an Interface `ElementStatic` and a variable implementing it:

```
interface ElementStatic {

    new(s: string, s2: any): Element;
}

declare var Element: ElementStatic
```

But the compiler complains:
`Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'Element' must be of type '{ new (): Element; prototype: Element}', but here as type 'ElementStatic'`.

Which means to me: somewhere in my code, there must be a declaration of `Element` with the type given. But there is none, at least I cannot find it. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `Element` is not in your code it's in `lib.d.ts` (or a variant of it) the default library for Typescript.

I found this out by pressing `F12` in Visual Studio Code, the popup, will list all declaration locations.

Comment: Can I extend the definition of Element then?

Comment: In my Visual Studio Code Instance, the `F12` popup simply says 'No definition found for Element'. :(

Comment: @Ferenjito If the cursor is inside the variable name `Element` it should take you to definitions

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @Ferenjito what is it you want to extend on `Element` If you want to add static memebers (access them by `Element.newField`) this is not possible, because the type of `Element` is an inline type : `declare var Element: {
    prototype: Element;
    new(): Element;
};`

Comment: @Ferenjito not sure why your environment can't find the definition, works on my macine :D

Comment: Ok, but how do I make Typescript to allow the following: `var c = new Element('p',{});`

Comment: @Ferenjito Not sure what you are trying to do. the type that is modeled by `Element` is this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element  Do you think that this constructor is missing from the definition of this type ? Or do you want to define your own `Element` type

Comment: I have legacy code to transform that makes use of mootools. Mootools introduces a new constructor function of 'Element' with two parameters. I did not find any type definition file for mootools, so I have to write my own.

Comment: @Ferenjito I don't see a way for you to add an extra constructor to `Element`. You can alias it `var MooElement :{
    new (n: string, attr: any) : Element
} = Element as any;`

Comment: @Ferenjito No you would have to change the constructor usage too `var b = new MooElement('a', {}); `

Comment: That is exactly what I want to avoid ;)

Comment: @Ferenjito sorry .. don't think there is a better solution ... unless you are willing to take lib.d.ts and customize it

Comment: I can't imagine that I am the first one encountering this problem

Comment: I`ll ask a new question with the issue more specific